# FlatList refresh indicator is blocking touch event after the indicator disappears

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm using ReactNative FlatList.

I can't listen to touch events on the space where the refresh indicator appears when I refresh.

When I refresh, the refresh indicator appears, and as the refreshing is done, it disappears.

But I can't click on the button(listen to press event) placed on the same spot as the indicator.

I tried the RN inspector on the device. When I tried to inspect the button, inspector found a `<RefreshControl>`, not  the button. But refreshing was definitely finished. Value of the `refreshing` prop was `false`.

I have no idea why it's happening.

Please can someone give me any hint or let me know if it's some kind of a bug?

Comment: Can you please share the FlatList props that you are using?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please share your code snippet. I want to check which props of FlatList you are using and you can take reference from here.
https://github.com/kajal-mittal/Samachar/blob/d4dc049ae2a38110d7fa88285cf732487800299c/src/Components/NewsScene.js

```
<FlatList
                         data={[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'}]}
                         renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}
                         removeClippedSubviews={false}
                         refreshing={
                            <RefreshControl refreshing={this.state.refreshing} onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)} />
                        }/>
```